# How to get member function pointer if exists in a template

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, pointer-to-member

To get a class member function pointer, we do the following:

```
return_type (Class::*varName)(paramType1, paramTypeN) = &Class::functionName;
```

The "functionName" should be known in advance.

The fact is, I do not (we should not actually) care about the function name, is there a way that , I could check the existence of "member function pointer", if it is not null, i call it.

I would like to do that in my template class.

If the template parameter object has a member function, which matches the signature I expect, I call that function.

The code is not valid C++ code, but it gives you a hint of what I am looking for.

```cpp
template< typename T >
class MyTemplateClass {

    void myFunction(T& object) {

        if constexpr( exists_in_class< T, void (T::*)(const int&, const int&) >::value ) {

                call_member_function_pointer< 
                    T, 
                    void (T::*)(const int&, const int&) >( object, 1, 2 );

          }
    }
};
```

If that is not possible, because you might have many functions with different names but with the same exact signature (prototype).
Is it possible to find a way to pass the function name as follows:

```cpp
template< typename T >
class MyTemplateClass {

    void myFunction(T& object) {

        if constexpr( exists_in_class< T, void (T::*)(const int&, const int&), FunctionNameIExpect >::value ) {

                call_member_function_pointer< 
                    T, 
                    void (T::*)(const int&, const int&),
                    FunctionNameIExpect >( object, 1, 2 );

          }
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you want to call any/all methods matching given signature? C++ doesn't have reflection yet to iterate over member functions.

Comment: I just modified the question, it could be any.

is it possible to specify the function name that we expect.

Comment: With *"functionName"*, it is possible (not as dynamic string though).

Comment: Is it possible to show a code example about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [std::experimental::is_detected](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected), you might do:

```
template<class T>
using has_my_function_name_t = decltype(&T::my_function_name);

template< typename T >
class MyTemplateClass
{
public:
    void myFunction(T& object)
    {
        if constexpr(std::experimental::is_detected_exact<void (T::*)(const int&, const int&),
                                                          has_my_function_name_t, T>::value) {
            object.my_function_name(1, 2);
        }
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d08082be5e4e48b5)

If you are more permissif in allowed signature (`Ret (T::*)(int, int) /*const*/`), `std::is_invocable` might be used.

Comment: Why is there a `*` in front of `my_function_name` when it is the name of the desired function and not a pointer to it?

Comment: It was to use member function pointer, but we don't use it currently.

Comment: I hope I have not done anything wrong, but the your code posted does compile but at run-time does not behave as expected.
The "expression" in the "if constexpr" is always false.

Comment: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d08082be5e4e48b5) added. Provide your which doesn't work if mine doesn't help enough.

Comment: Thank you for the demo, I know where is the problem and I cannot explain it why, in C++ it is OK to have the following:

    ```cpp
    void my_function_name(const int& a, const int& b) {  }
    void my_function_name(const int& a, const int& b) const {  }
    ```
But, once you have that, the expression in the "if constexpr" becomes always "false", please check:
[where is the problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20e14617992d8bf0)

Comment: For extra `const`, the signature doesn't match, you might prefer `is_detected` over `is_detected_exact` then. For overload, issue is that `&T::name` is ambiguous, so select neither.

Comment: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/117cea4f9fd26ea4) for less strict matching.